# help in plotting Minimize function

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Please help in plotting the following function versus $c2 \in [-1,1]$
$$S = \mathop {\min }\limits_{\theta 1,\theta 2,\phi 1,\phi 2} F(c2,\theta 1,\theta 2,\phi 1,\phi 2)$$

where ${\theta _i},{\phi _i}$  belong to the interval $[0,2\pi ]$.

Here my function:

```
S = 1/(32 Log[2]) E^(-I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) (8 (-2 E^(I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + 
        1/2 √(E^(2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + 
            c2^2 (E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(4 I ϕ1) + E^(
               2 I ϕ2) + E^(4 I ϕ2) + 
               3 E^(2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2))) + 
            c2 (1 + E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(2 I ϕ2) + E^(
               4 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2)))) Abs[Sin[2 θ1]] Abs[
          Sin[2 θ2]]) Log[
       1/8 E^(-I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) (4 E^(
           I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) - √(E^(
              2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + 
              c2^2 (E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(4 I ϕ1) + E^(
                 2 I ϕ2) + E^(4 I ϕ2) + 
                 3 E^(2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2))) + 
              c2 (1 + E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(2 I ϕ2) + E^(
                 4 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2)))) Abs[
            Sin[2 θ1]] Abs[Sin[2 θ2]])] - 
     4 (4 E^(
         I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + √(E^(
            2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + 
            c2^2 (E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(4 I ϕ1) + E^(
               2 I ϕ2) + E^(4 I ϕ2) + 
               3 E^(2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2))) + 
            c2 (1 + E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(2 I ϕ2) + E^(
               4 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
               2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2)))) Abs[Sin[2 θ1]] Abs[
          Sin[2 θ2]]) Log[
       1/8 E^(-I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) (4 E^(
           I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + √(E^(
              2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + 
              c2^2 (E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(4 I ϕ1) + E^(
                 2 I ϕ2) + E^(4 I ϕ2) + 
                 3 E^(2 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2))) + 
              c2 (1 + E^(2 I ϕ1) + E^(2 I ϕ2) + E^(
                 4 I (ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (2 ϕ1 + ϕ2)) + E^(
                 2 I (ϕ1 + 2 ϕ2)))) Abs[
            Sin[2 θ1]] Abs[Sin[2 θ2]])]);
```

Comment: There is an parameter `c2` too.  That means `c1,c2` are known parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I mean c2. I have modified the question. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far to find the minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make `S` into a proper function like this (clear kernel first):

```
S[ϕ1_?NumericQ, ϕ2_?NumericQ, θ1_?NumericQ, θ2_?NumericQ, c2_?NumericQ] := ...
```

Then write:

```
cx[a_] := 0 <= a <= 2 π
f[c2_] := NMinimize[{Re@S[ϕ1, ϕ2, θ1, θ2, c2], 
     cx[ϕ1], cx[ϕ2], cx[θ1], 
     cx[θ2]}, {ϕ1, ϕ2, θ1, θ2}][[1]] //Re
```

It only considers the real part as there's a very small imaginary part (floating point error?) which needs to be discarded.

```
Plot[f[c2], {c2, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]